# Please help correct my misunderstanding of this collection iteration, matching and deletion:

Tags: ruby, iteration

I am trying to iterate over an array of strings and remove those whose first letter is not a vowel. I know that there are more succinct ways of achieving this, e.g. #select, but I don't understand why the below does not work. Can someone please explain what's wrong with this code:

```
def delete_unless_1st_letter_is_vowel(array)
  array.each do |element|
    first_letter = element[0]
    if !first_letter.match?(/[aeiou]/)
      array.delete(element)
    end
  end
end

array = %w(knit taleb know high london alpha)
```

returns;

```
taleb
high
alpha
```

and I feel like it should delete all array elements except `alpha`. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Aside: I suggest replacing `if !first_letter.match?(/[aeiou]/); array.delete(element); end` with `array.delete(element) unless first_letter.match?(/[aeiou]/)` or  `array.delete(element) if first_letter.match?(/[aeiou]/).nil?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're removing elements from `array` at the same time you iterate over it;

First iteration:

```
element = "knit"
array = ["knit", "taleb", "know", "high", "london", "alpha"]
```

You remove "knit" and the remaining array is `["taleb", "know", "high", "london", "alpha"]`.

Second iteration. The block keeps working, but now it's turn to yield the second element, from the current value that `array` holds, that's "know";

```
element = "know"
array = ["taleb", "high", "london", "alpha"]
```

Third iteration. The same story, now it's turn to yield the third element, which now points to "london":

```
element = "london"
array = ["taleb", "high", "alpha"]
```

Fourth iteration. There's no fourth iteration, you removed the same number of elements than the current index.

As you use each, it returns the receiver, so there you get `["taleb", "high", "alpha"]`.

---

For the sake of simplicity, I think in this case `grep` is enough:

```
def delete_unless_1st_letter_is_vowel(array)
  array.grep(/^[aeiou]/)
end
```

And to avoid mutating objects, even if the programming language gives you all to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sebastian Palma, your helpful illustration of the problem has me understanding what was going on now, i.e. #each iteration moves along the array content indexes, but because I was telling it to delete the subject element (conditionally), on the next iteration it skips considering the 'next' subject element as they've all moved left by one position because one at the front that was being considered on last iteration was deleted. Thanks for taking the time to explain.